# how to change gitlab-ci runner build path

Tags: linux, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

How to change the gitlab multi runner build path.

in my server it have /home/gitlab-runner/builds.

I want to change this path to my secondary HDD that is mounted in the same server.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can change your runners build path by adjusting the `config.toml`. In the `[[runners]]` section add or change the `builds_dir` directory.

For further reference on runner configuration you can check out the documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section).

Comment: As per your instruction I have changed the path but I got this error message while build

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/git/gitlab/git-runner/993865ac’: Permission denied.

Comment: @PremAnand The user running the gitlab-runner doesn't have proper permissions. You need to fix that.

Comment: Hi can you please tell me what permission I need to give to the gitlab runner and how to find which user is running gitlab runner.

Comment: Thank you so much. I fixed the issue by changing the owner and group permission for that folder to gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner and it is working perfectly. You really helped me a lot thank you so much fairy. You are genius

Comment: Thanks! By the way, this also requires `gitlab-runner restart` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Does not work for me, after this change and running `gitlab-runner restart`, the systemd unit file still has the old `/home/gitlab-runner` directory specified in the `/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service` systemd unit file.

Answer (score 11):

On macOS I was able to find one more way (can be helpful if you have many runners, I guess):

1. Edit `~/Library/LaunchAgents/gitlab-runner.plist`
   and modify the path under `--working-directory` to whatever you want

   > e.g. from Terminal `vim /Users/Me/Library/LaunchAgents/gitlab-runner.plist`
   >   or using your favorite Text Editor
2. Restart it for the changes to take effect

   > `gitlab-runner restart`

Comment: This file is created by `gitlab-runner install` with the current working directory. Therefore you can also run `gitlab-runner uninstall`, `cd <new directory>` and `gitlab-runner install` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

One may prefer to setup build directories globally.

In the file `/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-ci-multi-runner.service` there is a line

```
Environment="DAEMON_ARGS=run --working-directory /var/lib/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner"
```

So, you may change `--working-directory /var/lib/gitlab-runner` to whatever path you want, and wouldn't specify the `--builds-dir` on every new registered runner

```
Environment="DAEMON_ARGS=run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner"
```

Comment: After modify the file, according to the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/init.html#customizing-systemd), you also need to execute `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart gitlab-runner.service`.